# Complex regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Consider the following regular expression :

```
^[:;][-^]\)$
```

List all the strings that exactly match this expression or, if there are more than ten such strings, describe them.

Comment: Since this is homework: What do you have so far?

Comment: Do you mean you need to write a program that lists all strings? You might want to edit your question (to make it sound like a question)

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Is there a particular symbol or portion of the regex that is confusing you?

Comment: That's an illegal regex in java, so it can't match anything. QED.

Comment: Masher, I don't think it's illegal in Java.  Why do you think it's illegal?

Comment: @Mike it was illegal before tchrist edited it; the `)` wasn't escaped

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the close paren is spurious, here is a slick solution:

```
% echo {':',';'}{'-','^'}\)
:-) :^) ;-) ;^)
```

Which is of course:

```
% perl -le 'print for <{:,;}{-,^})>'
:-)
:^)
;-)
;^)
```

Isn’t that cool?

And then of course, there's this:

```
              #!/usr/bin/perl
          use            5.010                                                                                     ;
        $stdout = 124.102.109.116;
                 open
                stdout                                                                                             ;        
              use    less 
  ${"\42"}         =         "\54"                                                                                 ;
                  say 
                  for 
                 @224                                                                                              = 
                  eval 
                  join 
                /\/\/\/∖/                                                                               => 
                   map 
                {"<$_>"} 
                  join 
                /\/\/\/∖/                                                                               => 
                   map 
                {"{@$_}" } 
           [qw{  |  [     }   ]                                                                                    =>
       [qw{    :  ;  % #     }   ]                                                                                 =>
   [qw{      ^  =  *  _  ~    }    ]                                                                               =>
[qw{     /  v  )  |  o   3  I   }    ]
```

which delightfully produces this:

```
|:^/ |:^v |:^) |:^| |:^o |:^3 |:^I |:=/ |:=v |:=) |:=| |:=o |:=3
|:=I |:_/ |:_v |:_) |:_| |:_o |:_3 |:_I |:~/ |:~v |:~) |:~| |:~o
|:~3 |:~I |;^/ |;^v |;^) |;^| |;^o |;^3 |;^I |;=/ |;=v |;=) |;=|
|;=o |;=3 |;=I |;_/ |;_v |;_) |;_| |;_o |;_3 |;_I |;~/ |;~v |;~)
|;~| |;~o |;~3 |;~I |%^/ |%^v |%^) |%^| |%^o |%^3 |%^I |%=/ |%=v
|%=) |%=| |%=o |%=3 |%=I |%_/ |%_v |%_) |%_| |%_o |%_3 |%_I |%~/
|%~v |%~) |%~| |%~o |%~3 |%~I |#^/ |#^v |#^) |#^| |#^o |#^3 |#^I
|#=/ |#=v |#=) |#=| |#=o |#=3 |#=I |#_/ |#_v |#_) |#_| |#_o |#_3
|#_I |#~/ |#~v |#~) |#~| |#~o |#~3 |#~I [:^/ [:^v [:^) [:^| [:^o
[:^3 [:^I [:=/ [:=v [:=) [:=| [:=o [:=3 [:=I [:_/ [:_v [:_) [:_|
[:_o [:_3 [:_I [:~/ [:~v [:~) [:~| [:~o [:~3 [:~I [;^/ [;^v [;^)
[;^| [;^o [;^3 [;^I [;=/ [;=v [;=) [;=| [;=o [;=3 [;=I [;_/ [;_v
[;_) [;_| [;_o [;_3 [;_I [;~/ [;~v [;~) [;~| [;~o [;~3 [;~I [%^/
[%^v [%^) [%^| [%^o [%^3 [%^I [%=/ [%=v [%=) [%=| [%=o [%=3 [%=I
[%_/ [%_v [%_) [%_| [%_o [%_3 [%_I [%~/ [%~v [%~) [%~| [%~o [%~3
[%~I [#^/ [#^v [#^) [#^| [#^o [#^3 [#^I [#=/ [#=v [#=) [#=| [#=o
[#=3 [#=I [#_/ [#_v [#_) [#_| [#_o [#_3 [#_I [#~/ [#~v [#~) [#~|
[#~o [#~3 [#~I
```

Comment: the paren isn't, as the answer is as `echo {':',';'}{'-','^'}\\)` returns `:-) :^) ;-) ;^)`

Comment: The shell echo trick is cool.  It worked for me in csh, bash, and ksh, but not in sh.

Comment: @Mike: Now you’re all wondering why I’m sending the output to *p2116-ipbf1708marunouchi.tokyo.ocn.ne.jp.*. :)

Comment: can u guys explain it in a very simple way, because im a novice for java..thx